# How to add c# xml cref comment for a complex expression?

Tags: c#, xml-documentation

I would like to add a cref for the expression `Bars[0].Name`

Here is the code but it generates 2 warnings
[image] [image]

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace MyProject
{
    class IFoo
    {
        public Bars Bars { get; } = new Bars();

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns true if <see cref="Bars[0].Name"/>  is empty or null.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>Indicates if name is empty or null</value>
        public bool IsFirstBarChildNameEmptyOrNull() =>
            Bars.Count == 0 || string.IsNullOrEmpty(Bars[0].Name);
    }

    class Bars
    {
        private List<Child> _children = new List<Child>();

        public Child this[int index] => _children[index];
        public int Count => _children.Count;
    }

    class Child
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

How can I add this cref without generating a warning?

Comment: What would you expect this would link to? Child.Name?

Comment: @KlausGütter Good question. What would developers expect?

Comment: I have found that if I add P: then the warning goes away. E.g.
<see cref="P:Bars[0].Name"/> 
But I don't know if this is a good solution or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do it directly like that.

You *could* get close by splitting it into two like so:

```
/// <summary>
/// Returns true if <see cref="Bars"/>[0].<see cref="Child.Name"/> is empty or null.
/// </summary>
/// <value>Indicates if name is empty or null</value>
```